# Javascript format-function for child tables with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

I have an issue with a function for child tables in my DataTable PlugIn..
I want to fill the table with data from my SQL-Database. But when I want to put the PHP-variables into my td's, my DataTable is broke (doesn't create the table).
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.. I hope you guys can help me :(
Here is a short code Example:

```
'<div id="'+data[4]+'tasks" class="tab-pane fade">'+
                        '<table>'+
                            '<thead>'+
                                '<tr>'+
                                '<th>Task</th>'+
                                '<th>Status</th>'+
                                '<th>Person</th>'+
                                '</tr>'+
                                '</thead>'+
                                '<tbody>'+
                                <?php
                                $sqltask = "SELECT * FROM taskscp WHERE status !='completed' AND status !='revoked'";
                                $result3 = $conn->query($sqltask);
                                while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
                                    echo"'<tr>'+";
                                        echo"'<td>'+" . $row3['task'] . "'</td>'+";
                                        echo"'<td>'+" . $row3['person'] . "'</td>'+";
                                        echo"'<td>'+" . $row3['status'] . "'</td>'+";;
                                    echo"'</tr>'+";
                                }
                                ?>
                                '</tbody>'+
                                '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
```

Comment: You be better off not trying to create js with php which creates the dom, like you wouldn't do `<?= \`echo $(node -e "console.log('Hello World')")\`; ?>`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Didn't understand it.. I tried it with a single echo but it didn't work either.. And sorry if I don't understand anything immediately - started studiying informatics and I'm still learning :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it! :) 
I removed the PHP code from my function and filled the table with an ajax request.